# How to center a div inside an input-group div?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

Given a nested `div` with the parent `div` having an `input-group` class, I need the nested div centered in the available line space or in the available next line free space.

This how I want it to look like at all times disregarding how many labels are there:

[image: centered]

```css
.small-numeric-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center
}

.small-numeric-container label {
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.numeric-small {
  width: 85px;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.rating {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff0000, #20c997, #0f5132);
}

.rating input {
  display: none;
}

.rating label {
  display: flex;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: 0.5s;
  background: #212529;
  border-right: 1px solid #ffffff;
}

.h-separator {
  width: 10px;
}

.rating input[type="radio"]:hover~label,
.rating input[type="radio"]:checked~label {
  background: transparent;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="input-group">
  <div class="small-numeric-container">
    <label>
      <input class="form-control numeric-small" max="15" min="2"
             name="0-scale" placeholder="Scale" type="number" value="10">
    </label>
  </div>
  <span class="h-separator"></span>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="rating">
      <input id="rating-label-10" name="rating" type="radio">
      <label for="rating-label-10">10</label>
      <input id="rating-label-9" name="rating" type="radio">
      <label for="rating-label-9">9</label>
      <input id="rating-label-8" name="rating" type="radio">
      <label for="rating-label-8">8</label>
      <input id="rating-label-7" name="rating" type="radio">
      <label for="rating-label-7">7</label>
      <input id="rating-label-6" name="rating" type="radio">
      <label for="rating-label-6">6</label>
      <input id="rating-label-5" name="rating" type="radio">
      <label for="rating-label-5">5</label>
      <input id="rating-label-4" name="rating" type="radio">
      <label for="rating-label-4">4</label>
      <input id="rating-label-3" name="rating" type="radio">
      <label for="rating-label-3">3</label>
      <input id="rating-label-2" name="rating" type="radio">
      <label for="rating-label-2">2</label>
      <input id="rating-label-1" name="rating" type="radio">
      <label for="rating-label-1">1</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like putting flexbox on the input group and auto margins on the inner box does the job.

By the way, the majority of your custom CSS can be replaced with Bootstrap classes for [flex](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/flex/), [margins](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/spacing/#margin-and-padding), [display](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/display/), [borders](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/borders/),  etc. I suggest a review of the library so you know what it offers. Don't reinvent wheels you already have.

```css
.small-numeric-container label {
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.numeric-small {
  width: 85px;
}

.rating {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff0000, #20c997, #0f5132);
}

.rating input {
  display: none;
}

.rating label {
  display: flex;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: 0.5s;
  background: #212529;
  border-right: 1px solid #ffffff;
}

.h-separator {
  width: 10px;
}

.rating input[type="radio"]:hover~label,
.rating input[type="radio"]:checked~label {
  background: transparent;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="input-group d-flex">
  <div class="small-numeric-container d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <label>
      <input class="form-control numeric-small" max="15" min="2"
             name="0-scale" placeholder="Scale" type="number" value="10">
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="box d-inline-block mt-2 justify-content-center mx-auto">
    <div class="rating d-flex flex-row-reverse border border-white">
      <input id="rating-label-10" name="rating" type="radio">
      <label for="rating-label-10">10</label>
      <input id="rating-label-9" name="rating" type="radio">
      <label for="rating-label-9">9</label>
      <input id="rating-label-8" name="rating" type="radio">
      <label for="rating-label-8">8</label>
      <input id="rating-label-7" name="rating" type="radio">
      <label for="rating-label-7">7</label>
      <input id="rating-label-6" name="rating" type="radio">
      <label for="rating-label-6">6</label>
      <input id="rating-label-5" name="rating" type="radio">
      <label for="rating-label-5">5</label>
      <input id="rating-label-4" name="rating" type="radio">
      <label for="rating-label-4">4</label>
      <input id="rating-label-3" name="rating" type="radio">
      <label for="rating-label-3">3</label>
      <input id="rating-label-2" name="rating" type="radio">
      <label for="rating-label-2">2</label>
      <input id="rating-label-1" name="rating" type="radio">
      <label for="rating-label-1">1</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yeah, I know there are bootstrap classes available for many of these purposes, I'm just unaware of which one to use to which case.

Comment: That doesn't really make sense. If you need styles, search the library docs. It works very well.

Comment: It's not very straight forward specially in the cases where you need to combine 5+ classes per element such as this one to get the desired outcome. In which case I find it a bit cumbersome to come up with the right combination. Unless you have a very clear idea about what each of these classes achieves individually, you'll waste a lot of time experimenting which is what happens in my case.